# Can we use merge fields(populate data from SFDC) using DocuSign Powerforms?

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to use DocuSign Pwerforms from Salesforce. Previously we tested DocuSign Templates and are able to populate the merge fields data from SFDC. Is there any way to populate Powerforms fields the way templates merge fields are populated.

Answer (score 0):

That depends if you know their value when the user click the powerform link. Powerforms are creating the envelope from a template after the user click the link and fills a few fields. You can modify the url (see here - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-populate-custom-document-fields-in-a-web-powerform) and if you can provide the information at that point - you can do it.