# Sending DocuSign PowerForm from Salesforce Account object

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a Powerform that people sign online. I want users to be able to send that same Powerform from SFDC account object. How do I pass account id to the Powerform. I have added merge field, but it is throwing error saying subject doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the PowerForm URL, you can set tab values in the document and meta-data (Envelope Custom Fields) in the envelope.

Example: You have a tab in the template's document with the data name "accountID". The `role` name for the signer is `signer`.

1. Set the tab to be locked. This prevents any of the signers from changing it. (Makes it read-only.)
2. Create a PowerForm from the template. Receive back the PowerForm URL.

   Example: `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=8883&env=demo&acct=7a9312b8&v=2`
3. Program Salesforce to send the PowerForm with the accountID set to "123":
   Example: `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=8883&env=demo&acct=7a9312b8&v=2&signer_UserName=Larry%20Kluger&signer_Email=larry.kluger@example.com&signer_accountID=123`

In step 3, you are programming Salesforce to dynamically create a URL that includes data from the current Account object. If you don't know how to do that, ask a new question in the Salesforce stackOverflow channel.

### More information

See the [Programming PowerForms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BKfyDSMoSE) video.

Comment: Thank you for helping. so if I add &signer_accountID=123 (dynamically from Saleforce) to the url , will it actually write to the docusign template?

Comment: It will write that that value to the envelope created from the template.

Answer (score 0):

This previous question seems similar:

[Can we use merge fields(populate data from SFDC) using DocuSign Powerforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947797/can-we-use-merge-fieldspopulate-data-from-sfdc-using-docusign-powerforms)

Does that help?

Comment: I want to dynamically pull values from Salesforce. Lets Say if user clicks button on salesforce Account object  - Send Application , the powerform should pull in Account name from the specific account .